# sympy Maximum-Likelihood: clarification of script from book

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

the code below is from the book "Python for Probability, Statistics, and Machine Learning. The clarification needed is for the plotting section. The problem is that "logJ" in the script is not-defined. However, the book provides this as the code to plot the graph. How do you correct (code) the plotting part of the script so it plots the output shown?

```
    # coin-flipping experiment using a Bernoulli distribution
    from scipy.stats import bernoulli
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import sympy
    import numpy as np

    #Simulating
    p_true = 1/2.0
    fp = bernoulli(p_true)
    xs = fp.rvs(100)
    print(xs[:30])


    x,p,z = sympy.symbols('x, p, z', positive = True)
    phi = p**x*(1-p)**(1-x)
    L = np.prod([phi.subs(x, i) for i in xs])
    print(L)

    logL = sympy.expand_log(sympy.log(L))
    sol, = sympy.solve(sympy.diff(logL, p),p)
    print(sol)

    #This is the plotting part, which does not work because LogJ is not defined
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    ax.plot(x, map(sympy.lambdify(p, logJ, 'numpy'),x), 'k-', lw=3)
    ax.plot(sol, logJ.subs(p, sol), 'o', color = 'gray', ms=15, label = 'Estimated')
    ax.plot(p_true, logJ.subs(p, p_true), 's', color = 'k', ms=15, label = 'Actual')
    ax.set_xlabel('$p$', fontsize = 18)
    ax.set_ylabel('Likelihood', fontsize = 18)
    ax.set_title('Estimate not equal to true value', fontsize = 18)
    ax.legend(loc=0)
```

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple of changes (logL to logJ, and map  made into list) displays the graph:

```
# coin-flipping experiment using a Bernoulli distribution
from scipy.stats import bernoulli
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy
import numpy as np
%matplotlib
#Simulating
p_true = 1/2.0
fp = bernoulli(p_true)
xs = fp.rvs(100)
print(xs[:30])


x,p,z = sympy.symbols('x, p, z', positive = True)
phi = p**x*(1-p)**(1-x)
L = np.prod([phi.subs(x, i) for i in xs])
print(L)

logJ = sympy.expand_log(sympy.log(L))
sol, = sympy.solve(sympy.diff(logJ, p),p)
print(sol)

#This is the plotting part, which does not work because LogJ is not defined
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
ax.plot(x, list(map(sympy.lambdify(p, logJ, 'numpy'),x)), 'k-', lw=3)
ax.plot(sol, logJ.subs(p, sol), 'o', color = 'gray', ms=15, label = 'Estimated')
ax.plot(p_true, logJ.subs(p, p_true), 's', color = 'k', ms=15, label = 'Actual')
ax.set_xlabel('$p$', fontsize = 18)
ax.set_ylabel('Likelihood', fontsize = 18)
ax.set_title('Estimate not equal to true value', fontsize = 18)
ax.legend(loc=0)
```

[image]

Also, I included %matplotlib as I tested in a Jupyter notebook